# Neo4j combine arrays from a return

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher

I have a simple node object.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String text;

    @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS")
    private Entry entry;

    @Relationship(type = "ATTACHED_TO", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<ContentAttachment> attachments = new HashSet<ContentAttachment>();
```

What I need is my return to return 1 array of all ContentAttachment ids. So Match (t:TextEditorContent) return t.attachments.ids. This would return an array of arrays, I would like all the ids to be in 1 combined array. Is there a way to do this with the query itself?

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid, I simply needed to match ContentAttachment and return id.